# Confused about the relation between $\ell^p$ and $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I know from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) that $\ell^p(S)$ is a special case of an $L^p$ space, namely it is the space $L^p(S, \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $S$.

There are also the $\ell^{\infty}$ and $L^{\infty}$ spaces. $\ell^{\infty}$ is defined as the space of bounded sequences with the sup norm. I read, also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity), that this space $\ell^{\infty}$ is a special case of an $L^{\infty}$ space, namely it is the space $L^p(\mathbb N, \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

One can consider a slight generalization of $\ell^{\infty}$: For any set $S$, consider the space $\ell^{\infty}(S)$ of all bounded functions $S\to k$ ($k$ either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) equipped with the sup norm. Question: *Can one also consider this space as a special case of $L^{\infty}(\cdots)$?* It seems, Wikipedia doesn't answer this question, in fact, the Wikipedia page on "L-infinity" doesn't even consider the space $\ell^{\infty}(S)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, on any set $S$ you have a counting measure $\#$. Then there are no nonempty null sets and thus the essential supremum (as in the definition of $L^\infty(S,\#)$) is just a supremum. In particular $\ell^\infty(S)=L^\infty(S,\#)$.